# [Android]min3d -collision detection and some stuff

Tags: android, 3d, detection

I,m using min3d framework on my device to make some car game, so i created some simple car model and simple and its moving, but i want to create ''physics'' and i need the collision detection which isn't provided in min3d (i won't change framework because i have android 2.1 without possibility to upgrade) i want to create it by my self but the problem is that i don,t know how to check if the plane collides with anything what i want to do is:
-create simple flat rectangle (not cube) and i want to place it in front of ''car'' and check if something gets inside of this rectangle and something does i want the car to bounce of it in reversed direction (the problem isn't to bounce but: how to check if something gets through my rectangle)

I have some other problem too:/

When i enclose my ''game''(haha) with a LinearLayout in xml everythong is going fine till i use the command to set the text with the value of rotation of a car for example -then is force close:/ I'm doing it form my class from which i load my objects (i'm providing my classes too)

I was searching for tutorials on the web but none of them was tlaking about 3d collision and even if it was about 3d there was too much code that wasnt need and i was loast in it so i dont get anything

I ask you royal users from stackoverflow to provide me example for creating the rectangle(if needed, because i can laod model from .3ds and .obj)and check if something gets through it(intersects?) not for entire code but just for the method how to do that, and how to refrsh the value of a car, in layout without a crash

By the way: my ''game'' is using qwerty keyboard as input (i,o,p,l keys)

Wanted to post my class here but its to much of lines and was getting erros so grab it on free hosting site, its scanned by avast already on my pc, it contains my entire project with min3d too.

My sources ready to compile and run are(with min3d -which isn't mine):
http://odsiebie.pl/ax1v1p5tam8i/KRL044.7z.html

thanks in advice:)

Comment: Collision and physics engines are monsters of code and logic requiring highly specialized training to create. There are no shortcuts. If you want to create your own, read up on quaternions and vector physics. I have built a physics engine and it took all of my abilities over a month or so. It did not include collision.

Answer (score 0):

an approach is to break it down to two dimensions (xy). imagine that your cars are 2D-Rectangles. in the moment you want to check collision, just check if any of the four corners of your "car" is within the rectangle of another car. might be not best practise but works for me.

instead of this you could use r-tree sqlite to check collision.